# Desasignar valores negativos en complemento a dos en JAVA

Tags: java, int, complemeto-a-dos

Tengo el script:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int c = 1;
        System.out.println(c & 1);
        
        c = (c >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320; 
        
        System.out.println(c);

        // Output: -306674912 ----> Valor sin complemento a dos 3993919788
    }
}
```

Quisiera que el valor `c` sea un `int` de 32 bits pero reasignado su signo.

Intenté usar el comodín de `>>> 0` para desasignar pero no funciona.

```java
System.out.println(c >>> 0);
```

Comment: Ese número no cabe en un int. Tienes que usar un long

Comment: Aunque lo almacene en un long me sigue dando negativo